# How to fix this error? Failed validating 'oneOf' in schema

Tags: python, swagger-2.0, connexion

I am creating an API using Flask, Connexion and SQLAlchemy to access a database. To do this I needed the following dependencies:

1. Flask-SQLAlchemy
2. Flask-Marshmallow
3. Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy
4. Marshmallow

When I run the file with the app instance using the command `python3 <filename>`, this is the error produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 16, in <module>
    connex_app.add_api("swagger.yml")
  File "/home/fidelis/repo/proj4/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apps/flask_app.py", line 57, in add_api
    api = super(FlaskApp, self).add_api(specification, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fidelis/repo/proj4/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apps/abstract.py", line 153, in add_api
    options=api_options.as_dict())
  File "/home/fidelis/repo/proj4/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.specification = Specification.load(specification, arguments=arguments)
  File "/home/fidelis/repo/proj4/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/spec.py", line 153, in load
    return cls.from_file(spec, arguments=arguments)
  File "/home/fidelis/repo/proj4/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/spec.py", line 107, in from_file
    return cls.from_dict(spec)
  File "/home/fidelis/repo/proj4/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/spec.py", line 144, in from_dict
    return Swagger2Specification(spec)
  File "/home/fidelis/repo/proj4/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/spec.py", line 38, in __init__
    self._validate_spec(raw_spec)
  File "/home/fidelis/repo/proj4/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/spec.py", line 214, in _validate_spec
    raise InvalidSpecification.create_from(e)
connexion.exceptions.InvalidSpecification: None is not valid under any of the given schemas

Failed validating 'oneOf' in schema['properties']['paths']['patternProperties']['^/']['properties']['delete']['properties']['responses']['patternProperties']['^([0-9]{3})$|^(default)$']:
    {'oneOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/response'},
               {'$ref': '#/definitions/jsonReference'}]}

On instance['paths']['/people/{person_id}']['delete']['responses']['200']:
```

Below is [the swagger.yml file](https://github.com/realpython/materials/blob/master/flask-connexion-rest-part-2/version_1/swagger.yml):

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: This is the swagger file that goes with our server code
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Swagger Rest Article
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json

basePath: /api

# Paths supported by the server application
paths:
  /people:
    get:
      operationId: people.read_all
      tags:
        - People
      summary: Read the entire set of people, sorted by last name
      description: Read the entire set of people, sorted by last name
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successfully read people set operation
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              properties:
                person_id:
                  type: string
                  description: Id of the person
                fname:
                  type: string
                  description: First name of the person
                lname:
                  type: string
                  description: Last name of the person
                timestamp:
                  type: string
                  description: Creation/Update timestamp of the person

    post:
      operationId: people.create
      tags:
        - People
      summary: Create a person
      description: Create a new person
      parameters:
        - name: person
          in: body
          description: Person to create
          required: True
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              fname:
                type: string
                description: First name of person to create
              lname:
                type: string
                description: Last name of person to create
      responses:
        201:
          description: Successfully created person
          schema:
            properties:
              person_id:
                type: string
                description: Id of the person
              fname:
                type: string
                description: First name of the person
              lname:
                type: string
                description: Last name of the person
              timestamp:
                type: string
                description: Creation/Update timestamp of the person record

  /people/{person_id}:
    get:
      operationId: people.read_one
      tags:
        - People
      summary: Read one person
      description: Read one person
      parameters:
        - name: person_id
          in: path
          description: Id of the person to get
          type: integer
          required: True
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successfully read person from people data operation
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              person_id:
                type: string
                description: Id of the person
              fname:
                type: string
                description: First name of the person
              lname:
                type: string
                description: Last name of the person
              timestamp:
                type: string
                description: Creation/Update timestamp of the person record

    put:
      operationId: people.update
      tags:
        - People
      summary: Update a person
      description: Update a person
      parameters:
        - name: person_id
          in: path
          description: Id the person to update
          type: integer
          required: True
        - name: person
          in: body
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              fname:
                type: string
                description: First name of the person
              lname:
                type: string
                description: Last name of the person
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successfully updated person
          schema:
            properties:
              person_id:
                type: string
                description: Id of the person in the database
              fname:
                type: string
                description: First name of the person
              lname:
                type: string
                description: Last name of the person
              timestamp:
                type: string
                description: Creation/Update timestamp of the person record

    delete:
      operationId: people.delete
      tags:
        - People
      summary: Delete a person from the people list
      description: Delete a person
      parameters:
        - name: person_id
          in: path
          type: integer
          description: Id of the person to delete
          required: true
      responses:
        200:
```

I can't figure out how to solve the error.

Comment: could you try change the people.delete response code from 200 to 204 ?

Comment: i think this may be a problem with your status code and the http verb

Comment: i had made  a small mistake and excluded the description part below the delete 200 (ok) response. That caused the error. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to include the description right below the delete response 200.This is the line i had forgotten.

```
description: successfully deleted a person
```

Comment: Hard to believe, but this answer did actually help me :D. I was pulling my hair out over this very problem, and it turns out that the stupid thing barfs when you don't have a `description` string for the response. Go figure :/